# df.Change[-1] producing errors.

Tags: pandas, slice, series

I'm trying to slice the last value of the series `Change` from my dataframe `df`.

The dataframe looks something like this

```
            Change 
0           1.000000
1           0.917727
2           1.000000
3           0.914773
4           0.933182
5           0.936136
6           0.957500
14466949    1.998392
14466950    2.002413
14466951    1.998392
14466952    1.974266
14466953    1.966224
```

When I input the following code

```
    df.Change[0]
    df.Change[100]
    df.Change[100000]
```

I'm getting an output, but when I'm input

```
df.Change[-1]
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#188>", line 1, in <module>
     df.Change[-1]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 601, in   __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2139, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 105, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3338)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 113, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3041)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 151, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3898)
KeyError: -1
```

Pretty much any negative number I use for slicing is resulting in an error, and I'm not exactly sure why.

Thanks.

Comment: `df.Change.iloc[-1]`

Comment: Thanks piRSquared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  What's happening is that pandas has no issues with `df.Change[100]` because `100` is in its index.  `-1` is not.  You happen to have your index the same as if you were using ordinal positions.  To explicitly get ordinal positions, use `iloc`.

```
df.Change.iloc[-1]
```

or

```
df.Change.values[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I really need to get into the habit of using iloc.